# Barra de Notificação com BigPictureStyle e 2 linhas texto?

Tags: android, android-notification

Preciso fazer uma notificação com esse aspecto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo achar nada parecido.

Consegui colocar 2 botões abaixo da imagem com:

```
            .addAction(R.drawable.sim, "Sim", pendingIntentYes)
            .addAction(R.drawable.nao, "Não", pendingIntentNo)
```

Mas realmente o que preciso e não consigo de forma alguma é colocar DUAS linhas ou quebra de texto no setSummaryText.

Preciso fazer uma notificação customizada? Se sim, como posso fazer dessa forma?

Edit:

Era examente isso que precisava, alguem sabe como fazer uma notificação assim.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que apareçam as 3 linhas de texto mais o texto "info" tem de fazer assim :

```
Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Text")
                .setSubText("SubText")
                .setContentInfo("info")
```

Ao definir BigPictureStyle assim:

```
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle big = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
big.bigPicture(bitMap)
   .setBigContentTitle("BIG TITLE")
   .setSummaryText("SUMMARY");
```

Quando a Notificação é apresentada expandida:

- o texto "Title" é substituido por "BIG TITLE"
- o texto "Text" é mantido.
- o texto "SubText" é substituido por "SUMMARY"

---

É também possível criar *custom notifications* recorrendo a uma *RemoteViews* passando-a ao método `setContent()` do *Notification.Builder*

Defina o seu *layout* da forma habitual num *xml*, depois construa a Notificação desta forma:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customnotification);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this) 
        ...
        ... 
        ... 
        .setContent(remoteViews);
```

Use os vários métodos disponibilizados pela classe [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) para aceder às *views* do *layout*.

Por exemplo `remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, intent);` atribui um *pendingIntent* ao botão `button1`

Comment: Sou iniciante como faria esse layout? você tem algum exemplo? como conseguiria colocar os botões iguais ao exemplo acima com essa barra de fundo transparente?
Outro detalhe como faria para o text ficar em Múltiplas Linhas?

Comment: O layout é feito da mesma forma como se fosse para uma Activity. Múltiplas linhas são vários TextView

Comment: Editei a resposta com explicação para obter 3 linhas de texto

Comment: ficou perfeito, era exatamente essas 3 linhas que precisava. Agora sim me atende perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela solução dada. Grande abraço